# dom in PHP saves new content over the old File

Tags: php, dom, xmlnode, ixmldomnode

Each time i do

```
$country = $this->dom->saveXML(); // put string in country 
$this->dom->save('country.xml');
```

It delets the **old** **country.xml** and creates a **new** **country.xml**
how can i append the old content of **country.xml** to the new content and save it again as **country.xml**

Comment: How many files do you what to have in result?

Comment: You'll have to rephrase your question because as it is, it doesn't much sense, especially that part: "how can i write the old content [...] to the new content" - What does that mean?

Comment: hmm.. image you have file country.xml with some countrys and you fetch now some other things and if you save this the old content will be overwritten and just what you fetched will be in the file country.xml how can i prevent that?

Comment: @Ivan Nevostruev there is just one file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to append it to the file, have you considered appending the new data to the existing 'old' DOM and then saving that to country.xml? This way will keep the document consistent and valid.

Comment: If you use `$this->dom = domxml_open_file('country.xml')`, it will create a new DOM from the file, and you can then append to it as you like.

Comment: hmm.. how can i put the content of the old file to a array? if i can to that i can write the new xml in a foreach loop thats easy

Comment: I've just realised, the above function will only work in PHP 4. If you're using PHP 5, you'll want to use `$this->dom->load('country.xml')`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then you want to append the new XML to the end of the old file?  This is a bit unusual for XML, however you could do it simply by writing to the file using

```
file_put_contents('country.xml', $country, FILE_APPEND);
```

rather than

```
$this->dom->save('country.xml');
```

Comment: Yes you have understood my question. However but the old xml will not be valid

Comment: If i do what you wrote i got each time i update the file with new content <?xml version="1.0"?> and more than one <?xml version="1.0"?> 
in a xml document is not valid xml.